# Amazon S3 Bucket Policy Isn't Saved

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to allow public access to an entire bucket, so I'm using the policy recommended in [this article](http://ariejan.net/2010/12/24/public-readable-amazon-s3-bucket-policy/):

```
{
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
         },
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I add the bucket policy (and change "bucket" to my bucket name) and save, if I click "edit policy" the policy doesn't display, and if I refresh the page the button changes from "edit policy" back to "add policy". It's as if I never added a policy at all.

I am the owner of the bucket and the items inside the bucket.

I've successfully done this on a couple of other clients' S3 accounts, the only difference with this one is that I'm accessing the account as a user rather than the account owner. Could I have the wrong permissions for my account? What permissions do I need to set a bucket policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a bucket policy:

1. You should be the owner of the bucket. (Which I guess you are indeed)
2. You should have `s3:PutBucketPolicy` permission. This is defined in your IAM user properties.

If above 2 conditions are met, then it should work. Could you check on above list and ensue that things are in place.

Comment: I had my client bump me up to the Administrator group. That seems to have done the trick.